# How to start labeling equations starting with zero instead of 1

Tags: labels, setcounter

My 'first equation' in a latex paper is the preparatory model equation. Then I start an algorithm development with a first step, then a second one etc. So I want my model equation to be labeled as (0), my first algorithmic  step labeled as (1), the second step labeled as (2) etc.

But \label does not have a counter so what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Setting counter to -1 will start equations from 0: `\setcounter{equation}{-1}`.

EDIT. Alternatively, `\tag{<label>}` can override numbering with a custom label (requires `amsmath`). Therefore `\tag{0}` would suffice without using `\setcounter` at all

[image]

The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    M = X_\text{Model} \tag{0}\label{eq:model}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    y_1 = f_1(x) \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    y_2 = f_2(x) \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

Reference to a model: eq. \ref{eq:model}.

Reference to eq. \ref{eq:1}.

Reference to eq. \ref{eq:2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tag{0}` would do without any `\setcounter`.

Comment: @egreg. I updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could decrease the equation counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtocounter{equation}{-1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
d
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```